# How to assigning Object into another object (not merging)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
var student={
   student1:{
      name:"John",
    }
 }

var student2={
       name:"Doe"
 }
```

Resultamt object should contain both student object with their object's name
Like this :-

```
 students={
    student1={name:"John"},
    student2={name:"Doe"}
 }
```

Comment: Your "resultant object" is not valid in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object spread to solve this.

e.g

```js
let student = {
  student1: {
    name: "John",
  },
};

let student2 = {
  name: "Doe",
};

let students = {
  ...student,
  student2,
};

console.log(students);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using spread operation you can combine them.

```
   const students = {
      ...student1,
      ...student2
    };
```